# Datatables header align when sidebar is collapsed: trigger class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) with scrollY actived and [AdminLTE2](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) theme:

```
acquisitionTable = $('#acquisitionsTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
//          "bLengthChange": false,
            deferRender:    true,
            scrollY:        '60vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller:       true,
```

the problem is the header align when sidebar is collapsed

[image]

and this problem is widespread but all the solutions that I tryed have failed.
I thought to call `acquisitionTable.columns.adjust();` but how can I catch the collapse and expand events?
This is the sidebar:

```
<!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
        <div class="user-panel">
            <div class="pull-left image">
                <img th:src="@{/static/assets/dist/img/fca.jpg}" class="img-circle"
                    alt="User Image">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
                <p sec:authentication="principal.name"></p>
                <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/}"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" class="treeview"><a
                href="#"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span>Administration</span>
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">5</span>
....
```

From the documentation (and I check it with debug mode) when the sidebar is collapsed the class `.sidebar-collapse` is added to body tag.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I fixed the problem with this code:

```
divW = jQuery("#contentAreaId").width();
setInterval(function(){
    var w = jQuery("#contentAreaId").width();
    if (w != divW) {
        acquisitionTable.columns.adjust();
        divW = w;
    }       
},100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried css `min-width` option, such as :

```
.dataTables_scrollHead table {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

also you may want to add :

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Comment: I once had the exact problem with Datatables, and solved it. The thing is, this is a css issue, So in order to reproduce the problem, we should first see the whole picture. Because, some css may be overlapping. And we can't see it all. What i would recommend is, you should put relevant css, some HTML with tables (not all of the table if large data), and script files into JSFiddle, or JSBin or here using `Code Snippet` of the post editor. And then we can have a clue on what is wrong there, and hopefully help.

Comment: I agree with you because in my page use several plugin and even the table is very complex. I've updated with a possible solution